# How to get the AxisX interval MS Chart Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to get AxisX interval for MS Chart Control in code behind. But when i try to retrieve the value, it returns zero even though it has a default value.

```
'Doesn't return the correct value, only returns 0
Dim XInterval As Double = mainChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval
'  
'
'This allows me to set the value and works just fine, but I also need to get it first.
mainChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 2000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MSDN article on the [Axis.Interval Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.interval.aspx):

> A double value that represents the interval of an axis. **The default
>   value is "Auto", which is represented by a value of zero (0).**

So, i you're using the "default value" (auto), that would explain why you're getting a zero back.

Comment: Well that explains that. I think i will dynmically set a value based on other logic. Thanks.

Comment: @tszoro Glad to help!  It is a bit confusing that they have a default value called "auto" that is really just zero :P

Comment: Does anyone know what is the logic behind setting that auto interval or how to get that logic? I mean the default value is zero (representing "Auto"), but what calculations happen if I don't set interval myself, how is the interval determined. My guess is that the interval depends on the spacing, but I am not sure.